# make a relation in parent and child catagery

Tags: mysql, parent-child

I have been developing a site for a boutique.

Their requirement is :

- They have three categories and product can be added in any of three.

**example:**

```
                    Jackets
        Men           -             Women
        |                             |_Top,Jackets, Bags,Pants.
        |
     Jackets, Pants, Shirts.....
```

Now this is easy but here is the complicated part.

They have another categories:

**example:**

```
Bavarian Garments
    ||

Products1
Products2
  ....
   ...
   ...
```

Please help me making the db structure.!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite get the question. Could you try reformatting it?

Answer (score 1):

Listen if you have limit for levels you can do :

```
SELECT *....
FROM category AS level1
LEFT JOIN category AS level2 ON (c2.category_id = c1.id)
LEFT JOIN category AS level3 ON (c3.category_id = c2.id)
...
WHERE c1.category_id = 0
```

if you have no limit on the number of children you can:

-write a mysql recursive function .then fetch all mysql data and make the parent/children matching under the prog. language (ie php) .save somewhere (if you have a config table somewhere) the number of levels yo u have, and implement a query string generator that creates the query string for a given number of levels. on each update/insert you should check if the number of levels is changed and store it.

Comment: This answer someone did answer it before ,all respect for him and his copy rights :) .

Answer (score 0):

Given a shop with categories and products, I would put the database like this:

Three tables: `products`,  `categories` and `productCategories`.

`products` having all product-related information, `categories` having the names of the categories and finally `productCategories` as a junction table having only to columns (`productId` and `categoryId` as primary).

Depending on your needs `categories` could have a column named `parentId` (to arrange categories like a tree) or it could implement [the nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) with `lft` and `rgt` columns.